# Juniper and EdgeCore dhcpv6-relay remote-id (option 37)

Tags: juniper, ipv6, dhcp, dhcpv6, dhcp-snooping

I have the following problem. I have minimal configuration of dhcpv6-relay agent on QFX5100. Before the QFX, there is an Edgecore switch on which DHCPv6 snooping is enabled. The problem occurs as soon as I turn on snooping option remote-id (option 37) on Edgecore, at that moment QFX starts dropping packets (Dhcpv6 packet dropped - Bad Options).

Is it possible to turn on some option so that QFX forwards a dhcpv6 packet including the remote-id? Or is there a problem in the packet format that comes from the Edgecore switch? I need option 37 from Edgecore access switch to identify customer port. DHCPv4 + option-82 works without problem.

```
root@qfx0# run show dhcpv6 relay statistics                      
Dhcpv6 Packets dropped:
Total               75
Bad Options         75
```

Trace

```
Jan  1 00:33:01.557548 [MSTR][NOTE] [default:default][RLY][INET6][irb.101] dhcpv6_packet_handle: Invalid packet, received interface-id 0x0 remote-id 0xb411924 in a non relay packet
```

Thanks for any advice

Libor